# dotnet core 3.0 unable to locate the dotnetcore sdk when opening solution in vs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to load the source code for ASP.NET Core MVC at https://github.com/aspnet/aspnetcore. However, when I cloned the project, checked out v3.0.0, and tried to open the solution in Visual Studio 2019 (v16.3.4), I got the following error for all the projects

> Unable to locate the .NET Core SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version

I have ensured the .net core 3.0 sdk has been downloaded on my computer, and running `dotnet --info` yields the following data:

```
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Looking in the `.csproj` file, they are all targeting

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
```

Additionally, I have ensured that the path to the SDK 'C:\Program Files\dotnet' is included in my PATH variable. I tried adding a global.json file specifying the sdk, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

**Edit**

Below is an example of the csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Description>ASP.NET Core metadata.</Description>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsAspNetCoreApp>true</IsAspNetCoreApp>
    <IsShippingPackage>true</IsShippingPackage>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);CS1591</NoWarn>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <PackageTags>aspnetcore</PackageTags>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

, and here is the folder with all the SDKs on my machine. 
[image]

Comment: Close and open VS. This solved mine a few times

Comment: What do you get if you run `dotnet --list-sdks` from the command line? Are you sure you installed the .NET Core SDK when installing Visual Studio? I would run the installer and check that workload was included.

Comment: when I do dotnet --list-sdks, it does include the 3.0 sdk (3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]).  Additionally I have opened and closed it several times with the same result

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue and I found the solution;
I hope you have the same issue as I do.

cmd -> input `dotnet --info`
copy .Net Core's "Base Path"
Just add it to your system's Path variable.

The variable name is `MSBuildSdksPath`

More details, you can check this https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/231

Answer (score 1):

Some possible causes:

- you need to restart the computer, because the environment variables are cached
- you need to restart Visual Studio, because Visual Studio caches, too (close all instances of it)
- you have installed the 64-Bit version of the SDK, but you need the 32-Bit SDK, or vice-versa.
- you have installed an old preview sdk, and need to enable preview versions in the options of Visual Studio (or download the non-preview SDK since it's RTM)

You could try one trick I learned: 
Open a command line prompt, and type `env`
get the path environment variable

It should have

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;
```

in it.

Now replace `C:\Program Files\dotnet\;` with `D:\Programs\LessPortableApps\dotnet\`, where `D:\Programs\LessPortableApps\dotnet\` is the folder where you put your dotnet-sdks in.

Then, set the path environment variable `SET PATH="bla"` to your new path, with the dotnet folders replaced.

And then start Visual Studio from the command prompt, e.g. :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

That way, you can use .NET SDKs when you don't have admin rights to install them.

**One more thing:** 
.NET Core 3.0 requires Visual Studio 2019, if you have 2017, you can only use it, if you have msbuild installed (same version as VS2019).

To install the latest (as of 2019) stand-alone MSBuild, go to: [https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) and Scroll down to "Tools for Visual Studio 2017" and choose "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019" 
(it's for users who don't want the full IDE)

[Direct link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16)

Comment: i've tried all the above, but nothing seems to work. I'm wondering if there is any further diagnostic information available  - for example is there a compile log somewhere  on my computer for the statement 'Unable to locate the .NET Core SDK' where I can check the locations that visual studio has checked?

Comment: Just to provide more information, I have added to my post the csproj file and referencing the SDK, along with the folder containing the sdk.  Is there any way to find out how visual studio is search for the sdk, and why it can't be found in that folder

Comment: @Daryl1976: Do you have Visual Studio 2017 installed ? If yes, you might need to update to 2019, and apply latest updates.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I downloaded the master branch in a zipped file from https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore. Then I ran into the same issue when trying to load AspNetCore.sln in VS Code. (All projects in the solution failed to load).

Using **dotnet --info** I see that I have these installed:

```
3.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

However, the SDK version specified in global.json in the solution folder is using 6.0.100-alpha.1.20523.3.

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.100-alpha.1.20523.3"
  },
  "tools": {
    "dotnet": "6.0.100-alpha.1.20523.3",
    ...other settings...
  }
}
```

So I changed both settings to "3.1.403". Upon reloading the solution, all projects loaded properly.

Comment: Nice solution when you only want to browse the source code

Answer (score 1):

dotnet sdk tools looks for global.json file in the current working directory or the parent directories
The dotnet SDK version defined in the global.json indicates which versions of the .NET CLI should be used.
In general latest dotnet sdk tools are used so no global.json is needed. So if you want to controll which version of cli to use then add global.json else it is not needed.

try deleting global.json from your project directory or the parent directories and tooling will default to latest available sdk tool

a typical global.json file content looks something like below

```
{
  "sdk": {
  "version": "3.1.102",
  "rollForward": "latestFeature"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Go to global.json.
- Check your SDK version
- Go to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1 to find your one
- Download it
- Reload all your projects

Answer (score 0):

For version 6.0.100-alpha.1.20523.3 need installed this
https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/6.0.100-alpha.1.20523.3/dotnet-sdk-6.0.100-alpha.1.20523.3-win-x64.zip

or DOWNLOAD prerelease version of Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

dotnet --list-sdks if you dont sdk download it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was, I have dotnet `5.0.103` version installed in my system, and in my `global.json` (path for global.json file - `C:\Users\userid\global.json`) file the version was set `"version": "3.1.100"`.

After updating the path from `"version": "3.1.100"` to `"version": "5.0.103"`, it started working again.

[image: dotnet sdk version]

[image: global.json]

Answer (score 0):

If dot.net core 3.1+ version SDK library does not install in your system then first install it, if already installed then Repair it.

[1]https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-3.1.409-windows-x64-installer